# Importing flat file into existing table with different column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if my google skills are failing me, but this has troubled me for a while.

I've received various outputs that all need to go into one predefined table, but the column names are different in each flat file (tab delimited txt), but ultimately need converting into a column already in the table.

I want to import file.txt into dbo.supplier in this fashion:

Address1 > street

Supplier Name > name1

and so on, but it also needs to be a nightly, automated script.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I don't seem to be able to find anyone asking the same question.

Comment: IF the column names are different in each file, how will you map them to the correct database columns?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server?  If you have something other than LocalDB or SQL Express you can use SQL Server Integration Services to create a package for this and then schedule it nightly using a SQL Agent job.  SSIS has mechanisms to let you create the column mappings during the import..

Comment: Do these column names change without warning, or do you know which names they are going to be in each file?

Comment: If you have a predefined list of possible column names in the flat files, you could run some type of script to rename them before the SQL import. Just run through all the possible names and replace them with the actual table column names.

Comment: You could also create an SSIS package with the SQL Server Import and Export wizard then set up a Powershell or batch file to call DTExec if a SQL Agent isn't available (SQL Express).  Just watch permissions on the account running the batch/PS script.

Comment: SSIS can provide you with this functionality, this will also give you the ability to name the columns on the fly. Just recreate your table every time it runs by using a TSQL execution task

Comment: I hear crickets, lol...

Comment: Alternative to SSIS: use SQL Server's built-in bulk copy command to import your file as-is, into a staging table that you create. Then, use standard SQL INSERT with a column list to re-map the columns. Here are two links to simple tutorials to get you started. You can Google for additional sites: https://www.lifewire.com/importing-and-exporting-sql-server-data-1019806   and   https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-use-bcp-in-sql-server/

Comment: @TabAlleman - no, the columns are static, but one day i need to import X file with X columns and then next day I need to import Y file with Y columns, both into the same table.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo - thanks for this, I think this may be the way to do it! With no real SQL experience, wrapping my head around how to get around it is struggling and this is a great help, will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @DavidP - I'm happy to have X script for X file, Y script for Y file and so on, I wasn't expecting 1 script to import all scenarios, plus I think this would be too complicated a solution for me :-)

Comment: @jimmy8ball - I need to update the table with new info based on file X with X columns and file Y with Y columns, deleting and recreating the table each import isn't an option!

Comment: @daiv_ recreating your main table every import may not be an option, but it might be worth looking at using a separate staging table for the import and merging the data into your main table. The staging table could be deleted and recreated each time without affecting your main table.